# Unable to add new members in GitLab.com

Tags: gitlab

Steps to reproduce:

1. goto [www.gitlab.com](http://www.gitlab.com) and login with your credentials
2. Select an existing Group/Project or create new Group/Project and select it

Expected Behavior:
You will see "Members" on the left hand ribbon.

Actual Behavior:
The "Member" link on left hand ribbon is missing.

Answer (score 2):

The Member link has been moved on left side ribbon under Project Information > Members

[image]